# Applying CSS to Element created in TypeScript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I would like to apply the CSS to the element created in TypeScript. Is this possible without adding the style in TypeScript (test.style.color = 'red';)?

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="testContainer">
  <p>Created in HTML</p>
  <!--  Created in TS-->
</div>
```

**My TypeScript:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    let container = document.querySelector('.testContainer')
    if(container) {
      let test = document.createElement('p');
      test.textContent = "Created in TS"
      container.append(test)
    } else {
      console.log('TestContainer not found')
    }
  }
```

**My CSS:**

```
p {
  color: red;
}
```

I tried to add classes to the elements, created in the TypeScript file. They were displayed in the developer tools of my browser, but the CSS wasn't applied.

Comment: If you're using a framework, use the framework. Don't use plain DOM manipulation because it will probably break in the framework (prime example: React).

Comment: Other than that, how do you know the CSS is loaded into the page? Did you link it? How is it going to be applied? It's one problem that the CSS isn't applying, and another that the CSS isn't loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why not work:**

The way Angular manage the .css (to isolate the .css of each element) is adding a prefix in .css. So if you check the .html using F12 in your navigator

You see a .css like

```
p[_ngcontent-ng-c474887881] {
  color: red;
}
```

And a .html like

```
<div _ngcontent-ng-c474887881="" class="testContainer">
   <p _ngcontent-ng-c474887881="">Created in HTML</p>
   <p>Created in TS</p>
</div>
```

(the _ng-content-ng-c474887881] can be another one, it's only to explain me.

So, when you create using simple javascript your "divs" has not the attribute _ngcontent-ng-..., and not get the .css

**Solutions:**

1. You can use a global .css (adding in styles.css or using
   ViewEncapsulation.None), but in this case the .css is applied to all
   the application, and to make the .css it's only to the element
   created you need add a class to your element to be more specific the
   .css
2. The another way is use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

   ```
     const container = document.querySelector('.testContainer') //(*)

     const div = this.renderer.createElement('p');
     const text = this.renderer.createText('Created in TS by renderer2');

     this.renderer.appendChild(div, text);
     this.renderer.appendChild(container, div);
   ```

   (*) I prefer use a template reference variable and ViewChild,

   In your .html

   ```
   <div #container>
     <p>Created in HTML</p>
     <!--  Created in TS-->
   </div>
   ```

   In .ts

   ```
   //I use static true because the div is NOT under a *ngIf
   @ViewChild('container',{static:true}) container!:ElementRef

   //and use
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.container.nativeElement, div);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation! 
This was a simplified version of i problem I had in a larger project and thanks to your detailed answer i could fix this problem and understand what I did wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add class to the element, created in the TypeScript file.

**TypeScript Code**

```
test.textContent = "Created in TS";
test.setAttribute("class","MyClass");
container.append(test);
```

CSS

```
.MyClass {
    color: green !important;
 }
```

Comment: please, not add !important any more :(

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is that it adds the class (and I see it in F12) but does not apply the CSS. Elisio explained in his answer why this is the case.